# Format function changed and unable to work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a system on **Excel VBA** that compiles employee attendance and calculating certain values. I was amending some codes when suddenly my earlier codes for:

**"Format(Now(), "Short Date")"** changed to **"format(Now(), "Short Date")"**.

Now my earlier codes that format the current date are unable to run properly. Attempts to change the First Letter just reverts back to lowercase and renders the format as a text rather than a function. (This applied to all my codes that ran the format function) 
Does anyone have an idea of why my formatting function suddenly changes and is unable to work?

Comment: You (or someone) have probably declared somewhere in the same VB project a method or variable named "format", or have named a code module or sheet module as "format".

Comment: In VBA function names are case insensitive. So format() = Format().

Comment: @TimWilliams I just realize I accidentally declared a "format()" sub in a module while using excel to record a macro. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @jacouh I thought the letter difference would pose a problem but it seems like what you said was right. My code can run normally. Appreciate your tip!

Answer (score 0):

You (or someone) have probably declared somewhere in the same VB project a method or variable named "format", or have named a code module or sheet module as "format".